# Use app bar globally in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, appbar

I would like to know if it is possible to share an app bar, with a refresh button, only changing the command of the button (which it would depend on the page).

Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can but you will have to manage the context of that global appbar per page that the appbar is coupled to.

I attempted this once and it was a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

There's a topic in the MSDN doc specifically on this: [How to share an app bar across pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150604.aspx)

The basic idea is to create a new page object which inherits from Page and which defines the AppBars. Your actual pages can inherit from this new type and get the AppBars created by it.

You can expose each Page's custom command from a property on the page and bind to that to pick up the matching one.